# ViewerSupport.bind doesn't work correct with entities

Tags: jpa, eclipse-rcp, jface

In my RCP-Application I have a TableViewer which is bind to a WritableList of persons:

```
input = new WritableList(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getPersons(), Person.class);
ViewerSupport.bind(viewer, input, BeanProperties.values(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "married" }));
```

If I create the persons in the getPersons() then everything works fine in my tableviewer. I can modify an entry and after modfication the new value will be labled in the table.
getPersons():

```
persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(new Person("Rainer", "Zufall", "male", true));
persons.add(new Person("Reiner", "Babbel", "male", true));
persons.add(new Person("Marie", "Dortmund", "female", false));
return persons;
```

But if the persons will be returned from an EntityManager, the modified entry will not be labeled in the table, although the fields in the Person objects will be set.
getPersons():

```
factory = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME,map);
entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Person p");
List<Person> persons = q.getResultList();
entityManager.close();
return persons;
```